# why is a | b is neither equivalent to $ \frac ab \in Z$ nor b mod a = 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand that this is the definition of divisibility

> Definition: Let $a,b \in Z$. We say that a divides b (or a is a divisor of b, or b is
>   divisible by a, or b is a multiple of a) if, and only if, there exists $k \in Z$
>   such that $b = ak$.

But then I come across this my lecture notes

> a | b is neither equivalent to $ \frac ab \in Z$ nor b mod a = 0.

1. Is this statement true?
2. Why is $ \frac ab \in Z$ not be an integer, since a divides b
3. Why is mod a = 0 not equivalent to a | b

Comment: It means is not equivalent to either of those two following statements. Two statements are equivalent if each implies the other. (Is this what you are asking?)

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a typo: $a\mid b$ is certainly not equivalent to $\frac ab\in\Bbb Z$; if at all, it is *almost* equivalent to $\frac ba\in \Bbb Z$. But even that claim has exceptions:

We have $0\mid 0$ because $0=k\cdot 0$ e.g. with $k=42$. However, we do not have  $\frac 00\in\Bbb Z$ because $\frac 00$ isn't even defined. Hence $a\mid b$ is not equivalent to $\frac ba\in\Bbb Z$.

Likewise, the value of $0\bmod 0$ is not defined: It should be the unique integer $r$ with $0\le r<0$ such that $0-r$ is a multiple of $0$, but of course $0\le r<0$ cannot be fulfilled. Hence $a\mid b$ isn't equivalent to $b\bmod a=0$, either.

(On the other hand, we *do* have $0\equiv 0\pmod 0$ and more generally $a\mid b\iff b\equiv 0\pmod a$)

Comment: hi thanks for replying, but I do not understand where is the typo, I have updated my question